# Cross-domain request without server control

Tags: cross-domain, dart

I decided to use Dart to work on a webApp to learn it and hope to see it spread. The problem i face today is the following :

I make a cross-domain request using a HttpRequest and since the api doesn't send an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, i end up with an error :

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.eveonline.com/account/APIKeyInfo.xml.aspx?keyID=vide&vCode=vide&. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3030' is therefore not allowed access. 
Instance of '_XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent@0x3918afae'
```

i found a few question pertaining to that problem but no real solution. I don't want to use a server side application as a proxy. I read that jquery has a solution that allow cross-domain request without the "Control-Allow-Origin" in the response but i would prefer to not use jquery if possible.

If any of you has a solution or a clue has where to look for one that would be great !

EDIT :  i finally built a small proxy in php even if i would have preferred a more "dartian" solution. Thx for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that is what you are looking for http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jsonp

Comment: i found that but that kinda look hacky. If it really is the only way to do it that will have to do but i doesn't come to that. Thx anyway.

Comment: another possibility:
https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/8m_IifbV26w

Answer (score 1):

In Dart's official documentation, 2 ways are mentioned for cross domain resource access.

One is setting CORS headers. If you have control over the server side, setting CORS header is the most convenient.

The other is using JSONP. But as you said, it is a bit too hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is an open bug: (9-Jan-14)
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15992

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.